# CakePHP3.X $query->hydrate(false) does not work for my code

Tags: object, cakephp

I am using tableRegistry::get() and that returns the query object. I want only data of the table which is return by find() function in CakePHP2.X version. For that I need to use "hydrate" as I read in one of the suggestion. Here is my code:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
    $this->maincategories();
}

function maincategories(){
    $postcategories = TableRegistry::get('Postcategories',[
            'className' => 'App\Model\Table\PostcategoriesTable', 
            'table' => 'postcategories'
    ]);

    $query = $postcategories->find('all',['fields'=>[
                'Postcategory.id',      
                'Postcategory.name'
    ], 'contain' => ['']])->hydrate(false)->toArray();

    pr($query);exit;
}
```

This code is still giving me the error "Postcategories is not associated with"

Answer (score 0):

remove the empty contain

```
$query = $postcategories->find('all')
    ->select(['Postcategory.id', 'Postcategory.name'])
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Yes this works for me now the "modified" and "created" gives the object in the record set. I use this statement :                                                     $query = $postcategories->find('threaded',[     
   'keyField' => $postcategories->primaryKey(),
   'parentField' => 'parent_id'])->hydrate(false)->toArray();

Comment: how can I Accept the answer? what I have to do Alex. Still my Issue is not completely resolved. I need to fetch latest 5 posts from each postcategory and i reached to the code :

Answer (score 0):

I am using "threaded" for find query
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 
            [name] => Web Development
            [active] => 1
            [lft] => 1
            [rght] => 6
            [created] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-02-10 14:11:19.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

```
        [modified] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-02-10 14:11:19.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [name] => Open Source
                        [active] => 1
                        [lft] => 2
                        [rght] => 5
                        [created] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
                            (
                                [date] => 2015-02-10 14:11:54.000000
                                [timezone_type] => 3
                                [timezone] => UTC
                            )

                        [modified] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
                            (
                                [date] => 2015-02-10 14:11:54.000000
                                [timezone_type] => 3
                                [timezone] => UTC
                            )

                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 3
                                        [parent_id] => 2
                                        [name] => PHP
                                        [active] => 1
                                        [lft] => 3
                                        [rght] => 4
                                        [created] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
                                            (
                                                [date] => 2015-02-10 15:57:11.000000
                                                [timezone_type] => 3
                                                [timezone] => UTC
                                            )

                                        [modified] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
                                            (
                                                [date] => 2015-02-10 15:57:11.000000
                                                [timezone_type] => 3
                                                [timezone] => UTC
                                            )

                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [parent_id] => 
        [name] => Technology
        [active] => 1
        [lft] => 7
        [rght] => 8
        [created] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-02-11 11:26:22.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

        [modified] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-02-11 11:26:22.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

        [children] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [parent_id] => 
        [name] => Frameworks
        [active] => 1
        [lft] => 9
        [rght] => 10
        [created] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-06-19 16:24:24.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

        [modified] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-06-19 16:24:24.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

        [children] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

)